# Typographical suggestions for enumerate labels in different environments

Tags: enumerate, typography

In my document, I modified the enumerate labels as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}
```

The issue is -- I am using the `amsthm` package and have created a theorem environment using the plain theoremstyle, which affects the label itself. Meaning that the environment formats the font of my label.

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
```

The renewed `labelenumi` I am using makes the difference from plain text even more evident.

---

labels in plain text:

[image: img1]

---

labels in environment - theoremstyle plain:

[image: img2]

---

Is it good conduct to keep my label formatted as the rest of the environment? (that is to say, don't change anything) I think so, but at the same time I can't decide what would be better in a formal document.

As the question is of typographical nature I don't think a MWE is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use upright Roman numerals in all cases. It's easy with `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definizione}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textup{(\roman*)},ref=\roman*}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Numeri primi}

Possiamo elegantemente classificare gli interi positivi
(ovvero non~nulli) in tre classi:
\begin{enumerate}
\item unità: $1$
\item primi: $2$, $3$,\dots
\item composti: $4$, $6$,\dots
\end{enumerate}

\begin{definition}[Test deterministici e probabilistici]
Un algoritmo per determinare se un dato $n$ è primo viene
detto \textbf{test di primalità}. Questo può essere
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textbf{probabilistico} se afferma bla bla
\item \textbf{deterministico} se afferma bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'd not typeset definitions in italics, which requires double emphasis for the defined terms.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[chapter]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definizione}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textup{(\roman*)},ref=\roman*}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Numeri primi}

Possiamo elegantemente classificare gli interi positivi
(ovvero non~nulli) in tre classi:
\begin{enumerate}
\item unità: $1$
\item primi: $2$, $3$,\dots
\item composti: $4$, $6$,\dots
\end{enumerate}

\begin{definition}[Test deterministici e probabilistici]
Un algoritmo per determinare se un dato $n$ è primo viene
detto \emph{test di primalità}. Questo può essere
\begin{enumerate}
\item \emph{probabilistico} se afferma bla bla
\item \emph{deterministico} se afferma bla bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The labels would be upright in theorems anyway.

Comment: Thank you, if I knew someone was going to straight up post working code I would have added a MWE! Your last observation (about typesetting definitions/theorems/tec) is one I'm still struggling with, because without typesetting them they become confusingly similiar and mixed to plain text -- and space is something I have little wiggle room for, so increasing the spacing before and after is not really an option. I do not know how to solve this issue, and since it's a thesis theorem boxes would be kinda weird. But I guess it's a question for another post.

Answer (score 0):

For the enumerate labels, you most likely want to do things a little differently than what you have. There are, in fact, two commands for printing the enumerate label, one that specifies the number format (and will be used not only for printing the label, but for references as well). The other is for printing the label and adds extra decoration like the parentheses. With your current definition, if you use `\label` and `\ref` to refer to an item it will print

```
nel punto~\ref{determinisco}
```

as

> nel punto (ii)

rather than

> nel punto ii

To get around this, you can define:¹

```
 \RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\theenumi}{}{\roman{enumi}}
 \RenewDocumentCommand{\labelenumi}{}{(\theenumi)}
```

Personally, I would lean towards using Roman instead of italic type for the enumerated labels and to do that, I would make the selection of roman type part of `\labelenumi`, e.g.,

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\labelenumi}{}{\textup{(\theenumi)}}
```

---

1, In 2021, we should prefer the relatives of `\NewDocumentCommand` over `\newcommand`. The former gives greater flexibility in parameters than the latter and also makes commands robust by default. However, for the various `\the*` commands, we need to use `\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand` instead of `\RenewDocumentCommand` because the latter would not expand at the right time thanks to the robustification and would end up printing the wrong number in references.